# Keeping local folders synchronized

Tags: software-recommendation, backup, sync, directory

After repeatedly losing data on encrypted drives due to some trivial combination of software and hardware failure, I would like to know if there is a simple tool that keeps local folders synchronized. Like a local "cloud" service that runs on one computer and synchronizes any changes in one folder to the other folder as soon as both folders are available. That way I can keep a copy of the most important files on a different hard-drive.

Answer (score 1):

You need `rsync` my friend; check out the man page and do some research for some more information. Rsync will copy files between directories in a very smart way; only the changes are copied.

So a one-liner like `rsync -a /path/to/importantfolder/ /path/to/backupdrive/importantbackup/`

Look through the nan pages for the syntax to get exactly what you want.

Then you can wrap this in a bash script and run it as a cron job or run it manually when you hook up your harddrive.

This is the roll your own solution. If your not a fan I'm sure someone has already come up with a canned solution for this.

Comment: Looks promising, many thanks. rsync going once, going twice, ... Let's see if there are more suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

**Deja-Dup**. It's included in the default distribution with the name "**Backup**". By the way, you are looking for a *backup* solution, not just a *sync* client.

Comment: +1 for backup rather than sync. Sync means that if your first folder gets messed up, when you connect the other drive it will get clobbered.

Answer (score 0):

If you want syncing folders on different computers (either in local network or over internet) to back up, you can use Bittorrent Sync (http://www.bittorrent.com/sync). It uses bittorrent protocol, which allows syncing rather big files quickly. To use it for back up you should install it on both (or more) computers, choose a folder to back up and share it to other (others) computers like read only. It is also cross platform (Linux, Win, Mac, Android).